# comments as normal nodes in database

Tags: database, database-design, content-management-system, database-schema

I am not a database expert. so I just ask it as a beginner.
I am going to design a database however I'm not sure if what I am doing is right or wrong in database designing.
The website should contain articles and posts and each post may have several comments.
I decided to treat all articles, posts and user profiles as node.
so I created a table called "node" and each "node" has a "content" as TEXT.
Now I am thinking whether comment should be treated as "node" or I should make a different table as "comment_nodes".
I am looking for the efficient way.

so, in one word: is it ok to treat comments as normal nodes or not?

thanks

Comment: Are you using NoSQL document-based database?

Comment: i'm going to implement it by CodeIgniter or CakePHP by using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Table Inheritance, and it's not a bad idea. For example, in Drupal, most things are a "node".

The main advantage is that it lets you have foreign keys pointing to slightly different things (of the same parent type).

I would use Class Table Inheritance in your case. You could do something like this:

```
NODE
id

NODE_POST
id pk fk node(id)
title
body

NODE_COMMENT 
id pk fk node(id) 
body 
post_id fk node_post(id) 
parent_comment_id fk node_comment(id)
```

Anyways, Google for Martin Fowler on Table Inheritance and make sure you understand the implications.

If you're using PHP then Doctrine will help you out with inheritance.

I'd also recommend Postgres over MySQL if you are going to have nested comments as Postgres does hierarchical querying better than MySql.

Comment: thank you so much. how about putting body inside node table? is it rational?

Comment: if all of the subtypes have bodies, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL then your design is incorrect.

Basically you have to think of data in form of tables, columns and rows. Each table should represent a business entity and not something abstract. A column represents a  property of the business entity and a row is an item (instance of the business entity). You would need to define primary and foreign keys.

You would need to give proper types to the columns and define indexes to allow fast searches.

So just to give you an example

```
=================================
|       Post table              |
=================================
| id    |   Title   |   Body    |



=================================
|       Comment table           |
=================================
|id     |   Post id |   Text    |
```

I would start from basic tutorials in MySQL (cannot recommend any though). Apologies if this answer is too basic.

Comment: thanks for your answer. if I have understood you correctly, I should make different tables for user profiles, articles,... too. and repeat those fields. another issue is that, a comment is not necessarily refering to a post and I have to add comment_type too. am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is right. You also need to figure out relationship between entities: `1 to 1`, `1 to N` or `N to N`. This will impact on your design as well.

Comment: ok, I would separate them.
how about this design? is it still problematic?

=================================
|       Post table              |
=================================
| id    |   Title   |   Node_id    |


=================================
|       Comment table           |
=================================
|id     |   Post id |   Node_id    |